# C++ Global Operator Overloading Design Issue

Tags: c++, c++17, operator-overloading

I have an issue with my current design.

I have a class that can be constructed with any 1 argument. If it helps conceptually, think of `T` as for lambdas.

```
// 1
template<class T>
foo(T) {/*...*/}
```

This class overloads many operators, such as `!=`

```
// 2
template<class T>
bool foo::operator!=(const T&) {/*...*/}
```

The operators are independent of left versus right order, so globally I've defined this:

```
// 3
template<class T>
bool operator!=(T const& lhs, const foo& rhs) {return rhs != lhs;}
```

As a result, I get a lot of ambiguous `operator!=` calls. This is because it tries to use `3`, converting the second argument to `foo` since it accepts all implicitly, then swaps the order of the arguments and calls the member function. I thought this would be avoided by making the arguments to `3` `const&`, but I was wrong.

I came up with a few options but I'm not pleased with any of them.

1. Make the constructor explicit (which ruins 40% of syntax-sugar, the goal of this class)
2. Remove the global operator
3. Put the global operator into a namespace, and then do `using namespace` when I need them

What are my other options?

Comment: If `<<` confuses you, imagine how it will confuse anybody using your code

Comment: Replace the operator<< with an explicit function name. Specialy if your "<<" is not streaming (which it might well do, can't tell from your code). Overloading operators and giving them new meanings (works like +) is considered bad practice period.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov It neither confuses me, nor is the implementation itself confusing. Further, I'm the only one using the code.

Comment: @PepijnKramer That's a great alternative. Unfortunately, the class is a syntax-sugar class and nothing more. Adding an explicit function actually defeats the purpose of the class. Further, this happens with others like `operator+` and `operator!=`.

Comment: I've edited the post to be about `!=` since it probably makes more sense that way.

Comment: Syntactic sugar should make sense (also to your future you). Trust me giving things clear names on what they do is more important then saving a little typing now. Specialy if you're coding for a job.

Comment: @PepijnKramer It does make sense. What doesn't make sense about the example in the post?

Comment: operator != not returning a bool, constructor with one parameter not being explicit. I'm not being harsh, I just have been coding C++ since 1995 and I've seen a few things ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer The `operator!=` was a typo in the question I've fixed. The constructor with 1 parameter not being explicit is incredibly common. e.g. `std::unique_ptr< int > p = new int`

Comment: That is total miunderstanding what unique_ptr does. It is even not template of constructor and is explicit, more precisely  explicit unique_ptr( pointer p )